# Jedox How to use it? Main ideas behind data points rules, data flows, ETL... Where to find that?

Tags: database, ssas, olap, olap-cube, jedox

I am .net developer with a general knowledge of N-dimentioal data bases. Have a previous experience with SSAS and now with Jedox. I found it very difficult because I do not have enough information - technical details regarding Jedox. Now working on a big project with many Cubes, dimensions data flows, but I am lacking of knowledge about the basis. Can you point me to where I can find information regarding Jedox? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Jedox manuals [here](http://www.jedox.com/en/services/downloads/) (bottom of page). The admin guide is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

For some basic informations besides the [Jedox Knowledgebase](https://knowledgebase.jedox.com/) you can have a look at the documentations as well as the lecture papers from [this](https://sites.google.com/a/cs.uu.nl/infombin/resources) course.

Also good to know is, that Jedox does have, different to other multidimensional systems, an extra dimension especially for the KPIs(measures). This means the actual numbers for All measures are saved in the column '#Value'.